# Mass file renaming (Linux)

Tags: linux

I have a directory in linux with lots of images having double underscore `(__)`, I have to make it single under score `(_)`. Lets say file name is `a__1.jpg`. I have to make it `a_1.jpg`. I have to do it for all files inside a directory. What should be the command?

Thanks

Comment: I think `mmv` a command

Comment: Yes read [`man mmv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/mln.1.html) called Mass Move and rename - Move, copy, append or link Multiple files using wildcard patterns..http://www.ss64.com/bash/mmv.html

Comment: Why -1? This is a valid question (although not on this site, so I voted for close and move).

Comment: Next time post Unix-Linux question @[unix-linux exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve this goal.

- If you have `mmv` installed (or are able to install it), you can do

  ```
  mmv \*__* \#1_#2
  ```
- If not, maybe `rename` is an option:

  ```
  rename _ __ *
  ```

  (but alas, here I am not so sure about the syntax.)